# sweet alert can not working on iOS [ PHP ]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert

I've problem about sweet alert working on webpage & android mobile normally,
But not working on iOS mobile.
how to fix this?

```
<script src="<?=$path?>/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=$path?>/jquery.sweet-alert.custom.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function aalert(text){
        swal("<?=$wording_lan["found_error"]?>!", text, "error"); 
    }

    function aconfirm(txt,link){
        swal({   
            title: "Are you sure?",   
            text: txt,   
            type: "warning",   
            showCancelButton: true,   
            confirmButtonColor: "#53E69D",   
            confirmButtonText: "OK",   
            closeOnConfirm: false 
        }, function(){
            swal({   
                title: "Success !!",   
                type: "success",   
                timer: 1000,   
                showConfirmButton: false 
            });  
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                window.location = link;
            }, 1000);
            
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If the library isn't working in a specific browser then you need to diagnose the issue yourself and fix it within the source of the library. That's obviously a lot of work. A much better idea is to find an alternative library which does actually work on all platforms you require.

Comment: I don't see any events/triggers which calls the functions you have mentioned. Its not working on all browsers(chrome, firefox, safari, etc)?

Comment: working all browsers, but not working with iOS mobile.